# Dynamically creating buttons from localStorage array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Been stuck on this for a while and wanted to get some input as to what I can do differently. I'm essentially taking user input and pushing it into an array, creating a button based on that input, then saving that array to localStorage. When the browser is refreshed, I want to grab that string and re-create those same buttons. Here is what I've got so far:

```
    function generateButton() {
      var create = $("<button>")
      create.attr("class", "btn btn-outline-secondary")
      create.attr("type", "button")
      create.text(response.name)
      buttonDiv.prepend(create)

      var cityString = response.name
      cityButtonArr.push(cityString)

      localStorage.setItem("cityStorage", JSON.stringify(cityButtonArr))
      console.log(cityButtonArr)
```

as well as:

```
function loadData(){

  var loadData = localStorage.getItem("cityStorage")
  var loadedArr = JSON.parse(loadData)
  //  

  if(loadedArr != null && loadedArr != ""){
  cityButtonArr.push(loadedArr)
  for(i=0; i<cityButtonArr.length;i++){
    var create = $("<button>")
    create.attr("class", "btn btn-outline-secondary")
    create.attr("type", "button")
    create.text(cityButtonArr[i])
    buttonDiv.prepend(create)
  }
}
```

It works almost perfectly, but instead of loading individual parts of the array ("atlanta","las vegas", "salt lake city") it only creates one button with the text of (atlantalasvegassaltlakecity). How can I break up the array when using JSON.parse? Or am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: `cityButtonArr.push(loadedArr)` you are pushing your entire loaded array into the first element of the `cityButtonArr` array. You want `cityButtonArr = loadedArr`

Answer (score 0):

```
function loadData() {

    var loadData = localStorage.getItem("cityStorage")
    if (loadData == null || loadData == "") return;

    var cityButtonArr = JSON.parse(loadData)

    for (i = 0; i < cityButtonArr.length; i++) {
        var create = $("<button>")
        create.attr("class", "btn btn-outline-secondary")
        create.attr("type", "button")
        create.text(cityButtonArr[i])
        buttonDiv.prepend(create)
    }

}
```

[Full code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kEOGK3IKIuGkqVLP4rQ1tKSHGPgYwPFi)